# Countability of set of functions from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $ \left \{0,1 \right \}$ under some conditions

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

The question given is check Whether following is countable or not

> $1).$The set of all the functions from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\left \{0,1  \right \}$
>
> $2).$The set of all the functions from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\left \{0,1  \right \}$ which vanish outside a finite set

**solution i tried**- In $1$ option we can see that number of functions is $2^{\aleph_0}$  which is uncountable

But for $2$ option i am not getting clue how to proceed  further  Seems like he is asking about the cardinality of set of    **compact support** functions .

Please help

Thank you

Comment: It sounds like you might be misinterpreting (2) as referring to functions with support contained in an interval of finite measure. Such a support can still be infinite, but the intended meaning of (2) is actually that $\{x\mid f(x)=1\}$ is a finite set.

Comment: but we have to find the cardinality of set with that function but in your comment it is cardinality of set of elements which maps to $1$,can you please elaborate?

Comment: I wasn't answering (2), just clarifying that you're not meant to count any function that's 1 on infinitely many rational numbers, even if all of those numbers are inside an interval of finite length.

Comment: In other words, don't worry about how the elements of $\Bbb Q$ are arranged on the number line. Just think of $\Bbb Q$ as $\Bbb N$, since $\Bbb Q$ is countable. You can interpret (2) as asking for the cardinality of the collection of all finite subsets of $\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 3):

For each $n$, show that the set of functions from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\{0,1\}$ that vanish outside a finite set of $n$ elements is countable. From here can you conclude that your set is countable?

For example, when $n=1$, we're looking for the functions that vanish at all but one point $x\in \mathbb{Q}$. Then we can easily see that there are two varieties of a such functions: (1) $f(y)=0$ for all $y\in\mathbb{Q}$, or (2) $f(y)=0$ for all $y\neq x$ and $f(x)=1$. Thus there are two functions for each $x\in \mathbb{Q}$, so this set is countable.

Comment: what is $y$ here?

Comment: $x$ was a distinguished element of $\mathbb{Q}$ (the unique element of the finite set in question). I used $y$ to refer to a generic element of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: i am still not getting this ,if each $x$ has two functions and $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ then still there are uncountable functions.Please can you elaborate your answer

Comment: For $n=1$, the functions are in bijective correspondence with the set $\mathbb{Q}\times \{0,1\}.$ A finite product of countable sets is countable.

Comment: Maybe here's a more constructive hint: Show that for each $k$, the functions of this kind are in bijective correspondence with $\mathbb{Q}^k \times \{0,1,\dots, 2^k\}$.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the cardinality of functions from Q to {0,1} is uncountable in both cases as, taking the first case, for a specific q, $f(q)$ could take any real value between 0 and 1 and this set is uncountable - each member of the range is a separate function.

If we restrict the range to 0 for a finite set of Q, say $q_1, q_2… q_n$, then for another rational point, say $q_0$, the function at that point $f(q_0)$ can still take an uncountable range of real values.

Comment: note that op wrote $\{0,1\}$ and not $[0,1]$